# Moisture adsorption on FR4 PCB

Tags: pcb

Although the adsorption of moisture by FR4 is quite low, what is the best way to minimize it or eliminate it completely?

Comment: http://www.humiseal.com/conformal-coating/

Comment: Minimise? conformal coating. Eliminate? ... probably operate in a vacuum :-)

Comment: @BrianDrummond It may be operating at 40 degC in 95% humidity

Comment: To eliminate moisture absorption, don't give it any moisture (duh).

Comment: Adsorption is strictly a surface phenomenon - is that what you meant?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Yes. It must gain no mass in a high humidity environment

Comment: put it in a potting compound

Comment: Use G200 material.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there are any fixing holes, it will be impossible to eliminate completely; using [Parylene](http://scscoatings.com/what-is-parylene/parylene-deposition/) can (depending on how it is applied) provide a complete barrier. although moisture can still penetrate (*very* slowly).

This is *very* expensive solution (not least because there are very few suppliers who can perform this operation).

The other downside is it cannot be effectively removed without causing major damage to the PCB. I have some products where the use of this sealant is mandated (they are in ship-board aircraft).

I only mention this to show there *are* solutions, if there is a requirement for complete sealing.

I would note that [different](http://www.isola-group.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/370HR-Laminate-and-Prepreg-Data-Sheet-Isola.pdf) [PCB materials](http://www.isola-group.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/FR408HR-High-Performance-Laminate-and-Prepreg-Data-Sheet-Isola.pdf) have different moisture absorbtion rates.

'Ordinary' conformal coat comes in a wide array of types, each with their own pros and cons:

[Acrylic](http://www.humiseal.com/products/acrylics/), [Urethanes](http://www.humiseal.com/products/urethanes/), [Silicones](http://www.humiseal.com/products/silicones/), [Synthetic Rubber](http://www.humiseal.com/products/synthetic-rubber/), [Water based](http://www.humiseal.com/products/water-based/)(!), some are [UV Curable](http://www.humiseal.com/products/uv-curable-type-ar-ur/).

There are numerous manufacturers of these products and which one to use depends on the specific application.

As Spehro notes, there are system level considerations with ancillary materials to consider as well.

Comment: Parylene usually peels off like a thin film, removing it causes no damage at all unless you start trying to scratch it off.

Comment: I have never seen it peel off and believe me, we have tried; there are variants of Parylene, but certainly this company http://www.paryleneconformalcoating.com/parylene-removal-rework-and-repair does not appear to make such a coating.

Comment: Maybe it's just the stuff we use where I work - we use it as a coating for CMUTs (ultrasound transducers) and it's easier to do the entire test PCB than just a small region around the device. The stuff just peels off when we want to reuse the boards.

Comment: Are you sure it is parylene? As effective as it is, it is pretty nasty.

Answer (score 6):

Simply covering most of the PCB with solder mask will reduce the **absorption** of moisture. As will using a better (and more expensive) laminate such as [Rogers 4350B](https://www.rogerscorp.com/documents/726/acm/RO4000-Laminates---Data-sheet.pdf)- perhaps an order of magnitude better.

**Adsorption** is a chemical process that occurs on the surface and can affect surface resistivity. Since you are talking about PCB mass, it sounds like you are actually talking about moisture **absorption** which is diffusion into the bulk of the material.

[Controlling Moisture in Printed Circuit Boards](http://www.superdry-totech.com/technical_articles/CALCE%20best_practices_controlling_moisture_PCB.pdf) is a useful paper.

From a system point of view, other than the bare PCB, it would be important to avoid components that absorb moisture- which would include plastic-packaged parts, but especially polyamide (Nylon) fasteners etc. which can absorb an enormous amount of moisture (as much as 10%)- enough to cause large dimensional changes as well as mass changes.